# react props function params not work in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, covariance

you can try this [online demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=4&ts=4.7.2#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBAUAHOBnMAnAlgOwOYEoIBeAPggDcB7TAE2IUUNIgG8BfAKA6nqTmwCuAWwBGIdEzLsuPIgkkQA5AEZFHIA)

```
let a: (p: string) => void = (p) => {}

a = (p: number) => {}

a = () => '1' // excepted error
```

2022-6-27:

I have knew something about this：[`covariance` and `contravariance`](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance).

But, I don't know why a blank arguments's `()` implicit type is the parent type of `(p: string)`?

What the implicit type is?

Comment: How does `a(1)` work. `param must be a string` but you pass an number

Comment: It actually works. `() => 1` is a valid subclass of type `(a: string) => number`. The input `a` is simply ignored here. Consider that you can write `() => 1` as `a => 1` without changing the behavior.

Comment: @bill.gates I mean ts require param must be a string 

Comment: @tsh I think `a` should be a required param for ts

Comment: there is no error in second example

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine that is the question, I think `a` should be a required param for typescript declare

Comment: @flyflydogdog  `@tsh` is right

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine ok... I know the point, but how can i make this?

Comment: You need to bind argument with return type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245616/discussion-between-flyflydogdog-and-captain-yossarian-from-ukraine).